# shifter of multiple elements in 2-dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

in Python, let's suppose I have 4x13 list. Inside this list, values on first seven positions are 1, while values at the rest of the positions are 0. List basically represents pack of cards, when 1 means we picked one specific card, and 0 means we did not. Now I need to gradually "shift" 1s inside the list, to go through all possible states of the list (there are C(7)52 = 133 milions of possible states).

I have writen this code below, which represents shifting of 2 cards in 4x13 list:

```
list = [[0]*13 for i in range(4)]

x1 = 0
y1 = 0

x2 = 0

counter = 0

while x1 < len(list):
    while y1 < len(list[0]):
        list[x1][y1] = 1
        x2 = x1
        y2 = y1 + 1
        while x2 < len(list):

            while y2 < len(list[0]):
                list[x2][y2] = 1
                print(list)
                counter += 1
                if counter%1000000 == 0:
                    print(counter)
                list[x2][y2] = 0
                y2 += 1
            y2 = 0
            x2 += 1

        list[x1][y1] = 0
        y1 += 1
    y1 = 0
    x1 += 1

print()
print(counter)
```

but to remake this code for 7 elements (which means using nested loop inside nested loop inside nested loop... - 6 times) seems to me as utter hell... Could there be some other way, please?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use combinations (i.e nCr)?

Comment: only lack of my knowledge... How should nCr works?

Comment: Combinations is a means of selecting elements from a list. There's a builtin for it, but you could also implement your own.

Comment: Actually what I need is function, which takes input [0,0,1] and will make output(s) [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,0,0], but not any duplicate outputs. Am I right there is no such builtin function?

Comment: there is in fact a builtin function. I've put it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your post in the comments:

```
>>> f([0,0,1])
[[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]]
```

There's a builtin for this in the `itertools` module, `permutations`, which generates all k-length permutations of a sequence without eliminating duplicates which are in different orders.

So to solve your problem, you need to generate all permutations of your list, which has time complexity O(n!) and then remove the duplicates with O(n) complexity.

```
from itertools import permutations
x=[0,0,1]
print([*{*permutations(x,len(x))}])
#outputs [(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0)]
```

Comment: This is slower than my awesome bad script. But it would be better to use a list of values instead of a list divided into foure lists... I do not think there is a good solution.

Comment: Slower? What about for large amounts of values?

Comment: It was not to say anything bad. I just think we prove how resource demanding it will be to calculate all solutions, and that it is not easy to find a fast method. I think `permutations` will be faster around n=254, we got 52 based on the question.

Comment: What's `n`, and how did you calculate that?

Comment: Also, this is somewhat different from the problem posed in the question - it only analyses the one you posted in the comments.

Comment: Yeah i know, however i think the comment was a simplistic version of what he wanted

Comment: Here is an overview of Big O Time Complexity https://miro.medium.com/max/875/0*JHbVuxeKZECh7nYS.png
I the comment n=3 and in question n=52
But Big O is the whole book by itself https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithms-big-o-analysis/

Comment: I understand big O, I'm a seasoned programmer. However, you seem to be discounting the fact that the time taken is heavily dependent on the contents of the array, not just the length. As an extreme example, ten zeroes has only one combination, which is nigh-instantaneous to compute, whereas half zeroes and half ones has 252 combinations. The average time complexity is somewhere between it, so a mixture of big and small O time complexity notation is likely required.

Comment: More exactly, this isn't a function of the length of your list, but a function of the contents of it which just happens to grow with list length.

Comment: n is the number of times I have to do the same work, where I expect working time to be constant

Comment: I looked at my script and I have made a mistake somewhere. I do not get the same time again. So you are of course right it's faster to use `permutations` from `itertools`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you definitely want a run time below O(n^2). n is the number of items, in your case 4*13. The best version of a script will be slower that O(n^3). - This is without analyzes whether you can reuse data or other data structure can be an advantage.

But here is a script that has less run time than your example O(n^7).

```
rows = 4 # The four colors
col = 13 # Number of cards
max_range = 7 # 7 cards

total = rows*col # See the rows and columns as just a list of values
counter = 0

for i in range(total - max_range + 1): # Go through all minus the range
    # Create a list of zeros and set the range to 1
    _list = [[0]*col for i in range(rows)]
    for i2 in range(i, i + max_range):
        _list[int(i2/col)][i2%col] = 1
    print(_list)

    # Move each value in the range to the end
    for i2 in range(1, max_range):
        end = total - i2
        for i3 in range(i + max_range - i2 + 1, end + 1):
            _list[int((i3-1)/col)][(i3-1)%col] = 0
            _list[int(i3/col)][i3%col] = 1
            print(_list)
            counter += 1

print("\n" + str(counter))
```

It will be a very resource demanding method. I think you need to reduce the problem to a more specific problem if you want a workable method.

For example:

- Why calculate all the solutions to make a choice?
- Can a better data structure make it easier to know what to do?
- Analyzes point by point what you need to achieve outside the code
- How should the code be split up to do small tasks so that it is possible to keep track of card status

Maybe this can help: [Abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (It is not intended as a solution, only as a small inspiration for the importance of data structure)

Another thing to keep in mind is that a list of 133 million 0 and 1 will fill at least 133 Mbyt. It will not be a good idea to save the list as it is a lot to spend on just shift cards.

**** UPDATE ****

Another option could be to use AI:

- [Game Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_tree)
- [Alpha–beta pruning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning)

**However, it really depends on what you are building**

Comment: For future users: The AST is parsing-related. It's not even relevant - it's one of several intermediate stages between reading a code file and constructing a bytecode object.

Comment: Why do you think you have helped him by giving him a function that will take several days to generate a list of all options. What can he use a list for!?

Comment: Would you like a generator instead? Also, don't assume pronouns.

Comment: The question is why he need a list. What will it help him with? And if he needs a list, is the pattern important from his example? Or do he asks about how he develops a method that take a little time? And the last option, is he just asking about a simple way to calculate the permutations? In my response I give an example of a script that prints his pattern and point out the time complexity. If that was not what he wanted then i try to inspire hime with not too complicated things.

Comment: I did not give an answer on using `permutations` from `itertools` as I thought it pretty much did not matter if he used my script or `permutations`. It will always take several days.

Comment: Permutations is understandable, with documentation all over the internet, whereas opaque code with short and uninformative variable names is not. For smaller test cases, this is useful.